# Userform VBA Change design based on user selection

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have created the below user form (Screenshot attached) which captures data within a mixture of text boxes and combo boxes and only enables the "Ok" button if all combo boxes & textboxes are complete.

The first box is populated with:

```
With ProjectIDProgram_ComboBox
.AddItem "Project"
.AddItem "Program"
End With
```

If the user selects "Program" I would like there to be an option to add multiple project IDs.  I.e. A plus or minus button next to the Project ID text box. Can anyone advise the best way to achieve this?

I can achieve the desired results through having two separate user forms however was hoping I could achieve this via one user form if possible.

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try with hidden design-time controls that you toggle visible at run-time, and if that doesn't look good enough then try implementing dynamic controls, and pray your layout doesn't need to get very complicated. Your question is currently essentially asking for a tutorial - there's no way you can get a decent, helpful answer that covers everything that needs to be covered *and* makes sense to have on this site. You'll find many *specific* Q&A's here, helping you with the many *specific* problems you'll encounter along way.

Comment: Since you are going to display multiply projects on the form then you may try to use Listbox with columns holding all text boxes data of a projext within a row.

Comment: Thanks both, I think I will stick to using two userforms :)